# kernel of $\mathrm{dim}(M/2)+1$-th power of the Green's operator of $\Delta$ on manifolds

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, manifolds

Where can I find the following result?

> Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian $C^{\infty}$-manifold, $\Delta$ be the Laplace operator, and $n$ be the dimension of
>   $M$. Then, $(n/2+1)$-th power of the Green's operator of $\Delta$  is an integral
>   operator defined by a continuous symmetric kernel.

I was told to check de Rham's book Differential Manifolds. I did and I am sure it is where Green's form is discussed, but I do not really see where exactly. There should be books with more contemporary wording? I do not really see where $(n/2+1)$ comes from.

Comment: Here is some heuristics of why $n/2+1$ is the correct threshold, assuming you know something about pseudodifferential operators: If a $\Psi$DO $P$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ has symbol $\sigma(x,\xi)$, then its kernel is given by $k(x,y) = \int e^{i(x-y)\xi} \sigma(x,\xi) d\xi$. This usually is to be understood as an oscillatory integral and in general only is a distribution.

Comment: However, if the order of $P$ is $m<-n$, then $\sigma(x,\xi) \lesssim \vert \xi \vert^m$. I.e. the integral converges classically and gives rise to a continuous function $k$. If $G$ is the Greens-function of $\Delta$, then its order is $-2$, hence $P=G^{n/2+1}$ has order $-n-2<-n$ and the previous arguments apply. You can have a look at Shubin's book on Pseudodifferential operators, though I doubt that it spells out your desired result anywhere.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment made me think $n/2$ sounds about right when I think of (the proof of?) Sobolev embedding to $C(M)$. I had simple cases in my mind where one has the kernel in the series form, like when $M$ is a nice symmetric space. But then the convergence depends also on the dimensions of the eigenspaces, and I don't really see how the dimension of the manifold and dims of the eigenspaces can be related. I might want to dig into Weyl's dimension formula...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal G_s$ be the Green kernel of $(-\Delta_g)^s$, $s>0$. For non-integer $s$, this can be defined on compact manifolds via the spectral measure of $\Delta_g$, and on non-compact manifolds via Bessel-type kernels, see e.g. [2] below.

Then $\mathcal G_s$ has a continuous kernel $G_s$ provided $s>n/2$, satisfying
$$G_s(x,y)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\lambda_j^{-s}\phi_j(x)\phi_j(y) $$
where $(\phi_j)_{j\geq 0}$ is a CONS of eigenfunctions for $-\Delta_g$ of eigenvalues $\lambda_j$ counted with multiplicity. Continuity holds since the series converges uniformly. Symmetry is immediate.

This is (originally?) shown in [1]. A more accessible proof can be found in [2, Thm. 7.2.18].

Note that, if $M$ is closed (and connected!), $-\Delta_g$ is invertible only on $L^2$-functions with $0$-mean, which is why the series starts from $j=1$.

[1] S. Minakshisundaram, Å. Pleijel, *Some Properties of the Eigenfunctions of The Laplace-Operator on Riemannian Manifolds*, Canadian J. Math. 1949

[2] P. Buser, *Geometry and spectra of compact Riemann surfaces*, 1992